# php: trying to merge multiple pngs together getting error

Tags: php, gd

Note sure what i am doing wrong here... but im trying to merge 3 pngs over into one and it is throwing an error

**Warning: imagepng()** [function.imagepng]: gd-png error: no colors in palette in C:\wamp\www\jeep\public\test\png_2.php on line 22

```
$x = 300;
$y = 300;

$final_img =  imagecreate($x,$y) or die("Failed in call to
imagecreate()
\n");


$image_1 = imagecreatefrompng('ae.png');
$image_2 = imagecreatefrompng('ad.png');
$image_3 = imagecreatefrompng('ao.png');
imagecopy($image_1, $final_img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $x, $y);
imagecopy($image_2, $final_img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $x, $y);
imagecopy($image_3, $final_img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $x, $y);


imagealphablending($final_img, false);
imagesavealpha($final_img, true);


imagepng($final_img, 'final_img.png');
```

Comment: Which line is 22 in your example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the first two arguments to `imagecopy` reversed. The order is destination, source. Correcting this may solve the error.

http://php.net/imagecopy

Comment: thanks i didnt catch that one.. i would vote you up but i dont have 15 rep yet take care